# Ignore multiple records in LEFT JOIN query by case

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, left-join

I am trying to use my query to find the specific Worker.wname that has none of his relations with the animal.wild is TRUE.

for example from the following table I need to return "Yossi" since he has no row with wild = t

```
wname |   type    | wild 
-------+-----------+------
 David | Capricorn | f
 David | goat      | f
 David | Lamb      | f
 David | Tiger     | t
 David | wolf      | t
 David | Wolf      | t
 Yossi | Capricorn | f
 Yossi | goat      | f
```

This the query i've got so far (which returns the TABLE above):

```
SELECT
    worker.wname, animal.type, animal.wild
FROM resposibility
LEFT JOIN worker ON resposibility.wid = worker.wid
LEFT JOIN cage ON resposibility.cno = cage.cno
LEFT JOIN animal ON cage.cno = animal.cno
GROUP BY worker.wname, animal.wild, animal.type
ORDER BY worker.wname
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT worker.wname
FROM resposibility
LEFT JOIN worker ON resposibility.wid = worker.wid
LEFT JOIN cage ON resposibility.cno = cage.cno
LEFT JOIN animal ON cage.cno = animal.cno
GROUP BY worker.wname
HAVING sum(case when animal.wild = 't' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
ORDER BY worker.wname
```

Comment: Okay I managed to use your code and to make it work I only changed `animal.type` to `animal.wild` and equals to TRUE or 'yes' (it's the same in PostgreSQL). so this answer was very helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You only need table `worker` and the simplest is to use the `NOT IN` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wname
FROM resposibility
WHERE wname NOT IN (SELECT wname FROM resposibility WHERE wild='t')
ORDER BY wname
```

Comment: I must have the cage and animal tables since the wild column i'm getting from the animal table. which has a foreign key with the cage and reposibility only has foreign key for cage.. anyway Juregen D has solved it for me. thank you for trying too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [bool_or](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-aggregate.html) as follow:

```
SELECT worker.wname
    FROM resposibility
        LEFT JOIN worker ON resposibility.wid = worker.wid
        LEFT JOIN cage ON resposibility.cno = cage.cno
        LEFT JOIN animal ON cage.cno = animal.cno
GROUP BY worker.wname
having bool_or(animal.type) is false
ORDER BY worker.wname
```